# How to get the new value of a text field in a Rails form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

```rb
<%= form_for(@mymodel, remote: true, html: { id: 'match_form' }) do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :match_id, style: "width:82px" %>

   <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary', id: 'match_submit', style: "width:38px;padding:0px" %> 
   <%= button_tag 'Cancel', class: 'btn btn-secondary', id: 'match_cancel', style: "width:52px;padding:0px" %>
<% end%>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
      $(document).on("click", "#match_submit", function(event){
        $.ajax('my_controller_method', {
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'script',
          data: {
            mid: $("#").val(),  // How can I get the new value entered in 'match_id' textfield here?
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
        }
      });      
    });
  </script>
```

I have the form and JavaScript block shown above.

How can I get the new value entered in 'match_id' text field in the JavaScript code?

Comment: What's the rendered HTML? Javascript will work with the final HTML, not the Rails template.

Comment: If I do an inspect, this is the HTML code I see for the text field in question - `<input value type="text" id="debit_match_id">`

Comment: Well, `$("#debit_match_id")` then

Comment: That worked! Thanks! If I would like to access the same value (of text field) in an `erb` code block inside the JavaScript function, how can I do the same please? (I would like to evaluate the value entered in the text field and show an alert if there is an error)

Comment: ERB code does not exist any longer at the time JS is executed. It gets compiled to HTML on the server, then sent to the browser, then JS gets executed. JS has no idea of ERB's presence.

Comment: I understand. But we can execute erb code inside JavaScript code block - is that correct?

Comment: Well, you can write whatever ERB code in your template, in the middle of your JS and everywhere else. But first, this ERB will be interpreted and converted to HTML and will disappear, leaving only the _result_ of the ERB code. Then, later, the JS code will be executed in the browser. This is why ERB and JS can't communicate at all. They live in two completely separate timeframes, in two different physical machines. They are from two separate universes entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that ERB is a template that lives on the server, then gets compiled to HTML (meaning, ALL ERB code disappears completely), then the resulting HTML is sent to the browser, then the JS code is executed.

JS will only see and work with the resulting HTML. It has no clue of the presence of ERB or PHP or whatever templating language was used to generate the HTML it works on.

The result of your ERB template will be `<input id="debit_match_id">`, therefore the correct way to select it in JS/jQuery is `$("#debit_match_id")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.text_field :match_id, style: "width:82px", id: "debit_match_id" %>
# add id in text field to get the value
```

By using `$('#debit_match_id').val();` you can get the current value of match_id text field:

```
data: { mid: $('#debit_match_id').val(); }  // get the new value entered in 'match_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JeremyThille for this answer:

`$("#debit_match_id").val();`

This gives the new value entered in the text field (debit_match_id is the HTML id of the text field. JavaScript works with HTML id and not ruby template id)

Comment: Or I could have posted this answer myself and you could have validated it :D

Comment: You could post the answer now - I will mark it - it would take 2 days for me to mark my own answer. I would rather mark your answer right now rather than forget to mark my own in 2 days :) So, please go for it!

Comment: plus 1 to both answer and question for this conduct :)